# How to uninstall awslogs-agent-setup.py?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, access-log

Only after using `sudo python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region us-east-1` on my Amazon Linux AMI, I found this tidbyte of Caution from AWS docs:

> Do not update the CloudWatch Logs agent using the RPM installation
>   method if you previously used the Python script to install the agent.
>   Doing so may cause configuration issues that prevent the CloudWatch
>   Logs agent from sending your logs to CloudWatch.

Now, how can I uninstall the python version to use the RPM installation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a writeup about [removing awslogs on CentOS](http://thoughts.stuart-edwards.info/index.php/sysadmin/linux/removing-cloudwatch-logs-agent), I guess you can apply this on Amazon Linux as well. I don't think there is an easier way than doing it manually.

*Edited as the link above is not reachable:*

These steps should be executed:

```sh
#Stop the awslogs service.
service awslogs stop

#Remove cloud watch related files.
rm -rf /var/awslogs
rm /etc/cron.d/awslogs*
rm /etc/init.d/awslogs
rm /var/log/awslogs*
rm -rf /home/ubuntu/awslogs-agent-setup.py
```

Then restart the server if required.

The CloudWatch logs agent should now be removed from the system. Ensure you log into the CloudWatch AWS Console to remove the log group:
AWS Console -> CloudWatch -> Logs -> Select the Log Group and click on “Delete Log Group”.

Comment: link provided is no more working and can you please help providing a command to uninstall manually

Comment: /etc/logrotate.d/awslogs might has been created as-well

Comment: In any case you should remove the package first depending on your system and then manually remove the garbage. For Debian/Ubuntu it should be `awsagent`

Answer (score 4):

There is another work-around for removing the Cloudwatch agent permanently.  If you installed the package using `rpm`, we can use `yum` or `apt-get` to remove the package permanently.

```
sudo yum remove amazon-cloudwatch-agent -y
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove amazon-cloudwatch-agent -y
```

Comment: There is no package called amazon-cloudwatch-agent at all

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html. if you have installed cloudwatch agent on a ec2 instance using this tutorial, the above commands helps us to remove it

Comment: The OP asks how to remove awslogs agent, not amazon-cloudwatch-agent. Two different packages.