# Not able to uninstall Cloudwatch agent on AWS EC2 instance using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I installed CloudWatch Agent on my EC2 instance (Amazon Linux OS version 1) to collect some metrics in the past. Now I am done with my metrics analysis and want to uninstall cloudwatch agent, to save the cost.

I followed the steps from  https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/systems-manager/latest/userguide/monitoring-cloudwatch-agent.html page, but my EC2 instance does not show up, as its not a managed instance. So this is not helping.

I can stop the agent using `sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -m ec2 -a stop` command,  But on instance reboot, agent would start again.

I dont see any document to uninstall this agent using command line. Removing metrics can be done, but I still want to uninstall this agent. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer (not the accepted one) on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387097/how-to-uninstall-awslogs-agent-setup-py#:%7E:text=Ensure%20you%20log%20into%20the,on%20%E2%80%9CDelete%20Log%20Group%E2%80%9D.&text=There%20is%20another%20work%2Daround%20for%20removing%20the%20Cloudwatch%20agent%20permanently) helped me.

Basically I had installed cloudwatch-agent using yum. So i could remove it completely by using following command.

```
sudo yum remove amazon-cloudwatch-agent -y
```